# Conditional import in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have a native library built for either node or electron.  The project importing this library uses the node implementation (for testing).  A further project requires the electron version.  Is there a way I can setup a configuration for a conditional import that is trumped by the parent project?

```
Project A (electron)
  |- Project B (node)
      |- Library (native node/electron)
```

So Project B would set the config to node, causing the Library to conditionally load the node native.  Project A could override that config to force the Library to load the native electron config.

How would I setup something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work so just commenting, but have you tried just `if (config === node) { import node from 'nodejs'; }` I don't see why that wouldn't work in theory

Comment: Conditional imports seemed feasible when I searched.  I'm just not sure how I can use JS/NPM to drive that condition.

Comment: what is the difference between the node and electron versions? Electron will run any node stuff fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if you're running in electron like this:

```
if(process.versions['electron']) {
    console.log('we are running in electron');
}
```

or

```
if(window && window.process && window.process.type) {
    console.log('we are running in electron');
}
```

Comment: It was all about dynamic library loading and your first answer nailed it.  Initially I was using cross-env to set the environment and switch based on that.  While the `process.versions` feels a little fragile it's slick compared to my hack and far less maintenance.  Thanks!

Comment: There are a few other suggestions [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2288)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the APIs, do you have a preference on which one to use?  Looks like this one involves less undefined checks.

Comment: The [is-electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-electron) library is a bit more thorough as it will work if `nodeIntegration` is disabled. The library is still only [a few lines of code](https://github.com/cheton/is-electron/blob/4acaa6cab8b527c57c6e56381e6f9766d57c56b2/index.js)